# Detect assigned IP and add to IIS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, iis-6

I have VPS with Windows Server 2003. I have one Dedicated IP which is already with IIS. Please help me, how can I detect assigned IP and add it to IIS. My VPS provider company says that assigned IP is already with VPS but I cannot see it with IIS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get your assigned IPs from your provider. If it's already bound to your network adapter, `ipconfig /all` should show you what you need.

Then, in the IIS, add that IP to the site bindings.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just checked and found that assigned IP is not shown by ipconfig /all

Comment: Then you'll need to get in touch with your provider to find out exactly what that IP is.

Comment: ok, I have written to them, please tell me how to add ip to site bindings?

Comment: It's pretty well documented on TechNet and MSDN and has already been answered on this site multiple times. Part of being a Sysadmin is reading the manual. We're not here to do your job for you.